# Java Prepared statement equal to date comparison on timestamp fields

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp, postgresql-9.5

I have two fields in table with timestamp. I want to compare the date is equal or not. attandencedate::date =  ? is not working.

Following is my code:

```
String AttendaceSql = "SELECT * FROM attandence WHERE attandencedate::date =  ? AND userid=?";
PreparedStatement pstmtAttendance = null;
pstmtAttendance = DB.prepareStatement (AttendaceSql);

ResultSet rsAtt = null;
try {
    Date dateFormat = new Date(logdate.getTime());
    pstmtAttendance.setDate(1, dateFormat);
    pstmtAttendance.setInt(2, userID);

    rsAtt = pstmtAttendance.executeQuery ();

    while (rsAtt.next ())
    {
        flag=true;
        AttendaceId = rsAtt.getInt("attandence_id");
        UserId= rsAtt.getInt("userid");
        attDate = rsAtt.getTimestamp("attandencedate");
        System.out.println(AttendaceId+","+UserId+","+logdate+","+attDate);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "You shouldn't glue variables directly into your SQL. Use query parameters instead" Well @khelwood he does use prepared statements.. Whats the problem here?

Comment: In table I have attandencedate field with timestamp datatype. And I have a variable in Java with java.sql.timestamp type. I need to write a select query in java, where attandencedate=variable. Only need to compare the date only, no time.

Comment: equal to is not returning any data. but less than, greater than all working fine.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No problem, other than he's completely rewritten his question since I left that comment.

Comment: I guess attandencedate::date is not returning 2018-12-09 format. Still its returning like 2018-08-08 08:51:59.284895 timestamp format? Who can I cast as date format such as 2018-12-09 for a column in postgresql DB timestamp.

Comment: That should work. Dates and timestamps are not compared using "a format". If the query doesn't return rows even if you are 100% it should you could try `attandencedate::date =  cast(? as date)` but I doubt it changes anything. If nothing is returned then you probably don't have rows for December 9th, 2018

Comment: You can run `SELECT * FROM attandence WHERE attandencedate::date = date '2018-12-09' and userid = ...` in your SQL client and see if that returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

in while loop attDate = rsAtt.getTimestamp("attandencedate");
Change this with getDate(); type.